React component using native HTML input of type date: All values get reset while editing in Firefox
I am working on a date picker component which makes use of the HTML element <input type="date" />. In Firefox 129.0.1, when typing 0 as day or month the two other parts get reset.
I replicated the basic functionality on codesandbox.io to make the issue reproducible:

Enter 12.12.2024
Go back to month part
Enter 0

Result: Day and year get deleted, but I would expect them to be left unchanged.
This behaviour is different in Chrome and when using <input type="date" /> without react. In both cases, the other parts are left unchanged when entering 0.
What causes this strange behaviour in Firefox?
How can it be solved?
Further information:

The input field needs to be controlled so it is possible to update the value from outside the component.
Not updating the state in case event.target.value is an empty string prevents invalid dates (like 31.2.2024) to update the state, although in such a case this would be crucial.


When you change the value to 0. This is an invalid date input value and the event.target.value is set to"" an empty string. When it is set to the state it updates the input field with an empty string so the old value is updated.

When you change the value to 0. This is an invalid date input value and the event.target.value is set to "" an empty string. When it is set to the state it updates the input field with an empty string so the old value is updated.
I suggest leaving the date input field uncontrolled by the React state and using onChange to update your state value to use it in your case and using the defaultValue for initializing the input value.
Preview my solution
